# when I am getting image path from nodejs then the error is showing image URL is not defined in array in angular 2

Tags: angular

html code

```
<label class="form-control-label">Product Code</label>
                <select class="form-control" (change)="selectProductCode($event.target.value)">
                <option [value]="code.Item_code" *ngFor="let code of data">{{code.Item_code}}</option>                  
                </select>
```

component.ts code

```
          *imgResponse:any=""
                imgUrl: string = "";
                imageToShow=[];
                isImageLoading: boolean;

             createImageFromBlob(image: Blob) {
            let reader = new FileReader();
            reader.addEventListener("load", () => {
               this.imageToShow = reader.result;
            }, false);

            if (image) {
               reader.readAsDataURL(image);
            }
           }

     productcode=[
        {
            Item_code:String,
        }
    ]
    data=[{
        Item_code:String
    }
    ];
    selectedProductcode=""

    selectProductCode(value){

        this.selectedProductcode=value;
        var data={
            productcode:this.selectedProductcode
        }
          this.dataService.fetchproductimage(data).subscribe(imageresponse => {
              this.imgResponse = imageresponse
             console.log("image"+this.imgResponse)
             this.imgUrl=this.imgResponse;
             console.log("URL"+this.imgUrl)
             this.isImageLoading = true;
             this.dataService.getImage(this.imgUrl).subscribe(data => {
               this.createImageFromBlob(data);
               this.isImageLoading = false;
             }, error => {
               this.isImageLoading = false;
               console.log(error);
             });
            }, error => {
              console.log(error);

        });

    }

      ngOnInit() {
        this.dataService.getproductlist().subscribe(fetch => {
            this.productcode=fetch.body;

            this.data=this.productcode;

        });
}*
```

service.ts code

```
import{Injectable} from '@angular/core'
import{Http,Response, RequestOptions, Headers} from '@angular/http'
import {HttpHeaders,HttpClient} from '@angular/common/http'
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map'
import 'rxjs/add/operator/toPromise';
@Injectable()
export class marketingService{    
    constructor (public _http:Http,public httpClient:HttpClient){

    }
    private url="/api/users/product";
    private url1="/api/users/fetchproductimage";
    private url2="/api/users/fetchAllproductdetails";  

    createcatalogue(model){     
        return this._http.post(this.url,model,{withCredentials:true}).map(res=>res.json());
    }
    fetchproductimage(model){     
        return this._http.post(this.url1,model,{withCredentials:true}).map(res=>res.json());
    }
    getproductlist(){       
        return this._http.get(this.url2,{withCredentials:true}).map(res=>res.json());
    }
    getImage(id: string): Observable<Blob> {
        return this.httpClient.get(id, {responseType: "blob"});
    }
}
```

**that is my code I am fetching the image  from the node js path 
everthing thing is going good but when the image is fetch it is showing errror**

```
body::{"productcode":"jd"}
```

path:::["./uploads/jd0.jpg"]

I am getting the path from nodejs but as we can see the image url is in array but when I define the image url in array it show the array is not defined.

that is the error i am using string when i getting path from nodejs

```
image./uploads/jd0.jpg
marketing.component.ts:113 URL./uploads/jd0.jpg
marketing.component.ts:120 TypeError: req.url.toLowerCase is not a function
    at HttpXsrfInterceptor.webpackJsonp.../../../common/esm5/http.js.HttpXsrfInterceptor.intercept (http.js:2480)
    at HttpInterceptorHandler.webpackJsonp.../../../common/esm5/http.js.HttpInterceptorHandler.handle (http.js:1794)
    at HttpInterceptingHandler.webpackJsonp.../../../common/esm5/http.js.HttpInterceptingHandler.handle (http.js:2545)
    at MergeMapSubscriber.project (http.js:1464)
    at MergeMapSubscriber.webpackJsonp.../../../../rxjs/_esm5/operators/mergeMap.js.MergeMapSubscriber._tryNext (mergeMap.js:128)
    at MergeMapSubscriber.webpackJsonp.../../../../rxjs/_esm5/operators/mergeMap.js.MergeMapSubscriber._next (mergeMap.js:118)
    at MergeMapSubscriber.webpackJsonp.../../../../rxjs/_esm5/Subscriber.js.Subscriber.next (Subscriber.js:95)
    at ScalarObservable.webpackJsonp.../../../../rxjs/_esm5/observable/ScalarObservable.js.ScalarObservable._subscribe (ScalarObservable.js:51)
    at ScalarObservable.webpackJsonp.../../../../rxjs/_esm5/Observable.js.Observable._trySubscribe (Observable.js:172)
    at ScalarObservable.webpackJsonp.../../../../rxjs/_esm5/Observable.js.Observable.subscribe (Observable.js:160)
```

Comment: This error suggests that you are seeing a different issue than what you've described "marketing.component.ts:120 TypeError: req.url.toLowerCase is not a function." Can you show your marketing.component.ts file?

Comment: I have mentioned above ,component.ts is my marketing.component.ts